# JTable chokes on custom renderer

Tags: java, jtable

I have a custom renderer in a `JTable`.  When my `JTable` displays, I get a `NullPointerException` on `JTable.prepareRenderer()`.  I'm not sure what part of my custom renderer isn't preparable, but I'm sure it's my fault.

Condensed version of my renderer (full version at [this spot](http://github.com/mathphreak/MYGP/blob/master/src/net/sourceforge/mygp/view/GradeRenderer.java)):

```
public class GradeRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {    
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object grade,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (grade == null) return new JLabel();
        Grade myself = (Grade) grade;
        int score = myself.getScore();
        setText(String.valueOf(score));
        Assessment thing = myself.getThing();
        GradeStatus status = myself.getStatus();
        AssessmentType type = thing.getType();
        // do some work with status
        // do some work with type
        return this;
    }
}
```

Code where I add the renderer (full version [here](https://github.com/mathphreak/MYGP/blob/master/src/net/sourceforge/mygp/view/GradeEntry.java)):

```
model = new GradeEntryModel();
table = new JTable(model);
// some work with table
table.setDefaultRenderer(Grade.class, new GradeRenderer(true));
```

Any pointers as to where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Turns out it's (probably) not my fault, as not setting the default renderer still causes the NPE.

Comment: You still haven't posted a SSCCE, with the simple case that doesn't work to back up the above statement. Maybe the problem is the data in your table, but I'm betting the problem IS your fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out some of my data in `model` is `null`.  That'd do it.

Answer (score 1):

The NPE message will give you the statement causing the error. So that is the place to start looking. Once you know which variable is null, you can start to solve the problem. We can't help you because we have no idea where the error is occuring.

The only think I can suggest is that you should not use "return null" to return a null renderer. You would set the text to "" or something like that and then return the renderer.

If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: D'oh!  Of course I shouldn't return null!  Why the heck didn't I think of that?
Also, I suppose this SSCCE isn't very Short or Self Contained, although part of the problem is that I have no idea where the error is occurring as well.

Comment: Actually, though, this doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: I know you have no idea where the error occurs, which is why you create a SSCCE. You start with something simple that works. Then you add a custom renderer. If it works great, if not then you know where the problem is. The idea of the SSCCE is to isolate the problem, then we can provide assistance if you can't figure out why its causing a problem. Based on the code provided we can't begin to guess whats wrong.

Comment: Make it work, then add back features until it breaks?  Brilliant.

Comment: Wow.  I get my NPE even without adding my custom renderer.  Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with camickr, the NPE is telling you what is null so that should give you a clue.

But looking at your code i guess

```
 if (grade == null) return null;
```

returning null is a good way to trigger a NullPointerException

Comment: But returning new JLabel() doesn't fix this.